# How can we bind with specific datatype while converting XML to POJO using jakson

Tags: java

```
@JaksonXmlRootElement(LocalName = "root")
Class A{
@JaksonXMLProperty(localName = "name")
protected B b;
@JaksonXMLProperty(localName = "surname")
Protected String c;
}

Class B{
private String ab;
private String bb;
}

XML data:
<root>
 <name>xyz</name>
 <surname>mno</surname>
</root>
```

this is my class structure and XML data. I am able to convert it to a pojo where all fields are marked as String, but with custom Datatype i am getting target not found exception. Is there any way to do such conversion?

Comment: I couldn't understand exactly what you want. Could you also add the XML content of what you expect to the question?

Comment: If your embedded object only has primitive types it should work just fine, otherwise you have to add your own custom serializer and deserializer.

Comment: Could you provide the example you attempted with the `custom Datatype`.  As long as all classes are annotated (or designed properly) you shouldn't have any issues.  Also, can you show how you're building the `ObjectMapper`?